# Test marked @JdbcTest is failing when using Schedulers.boundedElastic()

Tags: java, jdbc, project-reactor

In the the test class `JdbcWithMonoTest` there are 2 tests `foo` and `bar`. The only difference between those 2 tests is that `bar` is written with `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

When I run a both tests the results are that `foo` is passing as expected and `bar` is failing with message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextMatches" failed (predicate failed on value: [])

Why test `bar` is failing?

I use java15.

```
@JdbcTest
@Sql(statements =
    """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOO_TABLE
        (
            id                   bigint         not null identity,
            valid                bit            not null
        );
           INSERT INTO FOO_TABLE (
           id, valid) 
           VALUES 
           (1, 0),
           (2, 1);
        """
)
public class JdbcWithMonoTest {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM FOO_TABLE";

    @Test
    void foo() {
        final Mono<List<Map<String, Object>>> result = Mono.fromCallable(() -> jdbcTemplate.queryForList(QUERY))
            .log();
        StepVerifier.create(result).expectNextMatches(list -> !list.isEmpty()).verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void bar() {
        final Mono<List<Map<String, Object>>> result = Mono.fromCallable(() -> jdbcTemplate.queryForList(QUERY))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .log();
        StepVerifier.create(result).expectNextMatches(list -> !list.isEmpty()).verifyComplete();
    }
}
```